# How to get all module from subModule, using *ngFor loop in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**TS-code:**

modules is an array of objects, which itself contain a nested array of object.

```
const modules =[{ 
   id: 1,
   module: 'Training Module',
   subModules: [{
        id: 2,
        module: 'Group Creation'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        module: 'Sub Group Creation'
      }, {
        id: 4,
        module: 'Training'
      }, {
        id: 5,
        module: 'Daily Attendance'
      }
    ]
}];
```

**HTML-code:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let module of modules">
  <td>{{ item.subModules[0].module }}</td>    <!-- giving Group Creation -->     
</tr>
```

Expected Output
[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrNGx.png)

Comment: Do you want to iterate over the submodules of each module? And will there be more than 1 module in the `modules` array? I mean, it's better to see the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a virtual container, if you do not want to add an additional element, like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let module of modules">
  <td>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let subModule of item.subModules">
      {{ subModule.module }} 
    </ng-container>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Alternatively, you could create a pipe, that formats the names of your submodules by for example comma separation.